# Can a image's zoomed-in view on the LCD screen be saved on a Canon 60D?

Tags: canon-60d

After taking a picture, I zoomed in on the LCD screen. Can I save this zoomed-in view? I tried to save using raw mode, but cannot seem to do.

Comment: What do you mean by 'magnified'?

Comment: After the picture was taken , it was magnified for viewing on screen.

Answer (score 2):

No. The camera captures the image as it is projected on the image sensor. When you zoom in using Live View to see a specific area in more detail on the rear LCD screen you are only magnifying a part of the image that is projected on the image sensor. This is for the purpose of allowing better manual focus or other factors related to composition or exposure of the image, but the camera is not designed to capture what is displayed on the rear LCD screen.

If you are viewing an image you have already taken then the magnification is there for you to be able to review the image in greater detail. Again, the camera is not designed to capture what is displayed on the rear LCD screen.